# My votes are wrong but are now locked

Tags: support

My votes on the answers of this question: [What happens if I have two Pledges of Loyalty attached to a creature?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/19091/what-happens-if-i-have-two-pledges-of-loyalty-attached-to-a-creature) are wrong. 
But they are now locked in and can only change if the answers are changed. Can someone unlock my votes or remove them so I can correct my mistakes?

Answer (score 2):

Two out of three of the answers have been edited since you asked this question, so you can already change your votes there.

Comment: Except the correct one :p